# React-Leaflet Mini Map - Custom zoom in MiniMap

Tags: react-leaflet

I am using the react leaflet mini map sample from https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-react-control/

I would like to add a small zoom control to the mini map.

I have added some buttons but I find that my button events are triggered after the default minimap bounds click event.

```
 // Clicking a point on the minimap sets the parent's map center
  const onClick = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      parentMap.setView(e.latlng, parentMap.getZoom())
    },
    [parentMap],
  )
  useMapEvent('click', onClick)
```

Is there a way to allow my controls onClick to occur before the useMapEvent click onclick event handler?

I created a minimap button component

```
import React from 'react';

export interface MiniMapButtonProps {
    onZoomIn: (event: void) => void;
    onZoomOut: (event: void) => void;
}

export const MiniMapButton: React.FC<MiniMapButtonProps> = ({ onZoomIn, onZoomOut }) => {

    function zoomIn(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>) {
        onZoomIn();
    }

    function zoomOut(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>) {
        onZoomOut();
    }

    return (
        <div class="leaflet-control-zoom leaflet-bar-tiny leaflet-control">
            <a class="leaflet-control-zoom-in-tiny" onClick={ zoomIn} href="#" title="Zoom in" role="button" aria-label="Zoom in" aria-disabled="false"><span aria-hidden="true">+</span></a>
            <a class="leaflet-control-zoom-out-tiny" onClick={zoomOut} href="#" title="Zoom out" role="button" aria-label="Zoom out" aria-disabled="false"><span aria-hidden="true">−</span></a>
        </div>);
};
```

I then modified the miniMapBounds component to handle the events

```
    import React, { useCallback, useMemo, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Rectangle, useMap, useMapEvent } from 'react-leaflet';
import { useEventHandlers } from '@react-leaflet/core';
import { LatLngExpression } from 'leaflet';
import { MiniMapButton } from './MiniMapButton';

export interface MiniMapBoundsProps {
    parentMap: L.Map,
    zoomDifference: number    
}

export const MiniMapBounds: React.FC<MiniMapBoundsProps> = ({ parentMap, zoomDifference }) => {
    const minimap = useMap();
    const ignoreClick = useRef(false);

    // Clicking a point on the minimap sets the parent's map center
    const onClick = useCallback((e: { latlng: LatLngExpression; }) => {
            parentMap.setView(e.latlng, parentMap.getZoom());
    },
        [parentMap]
    );
    useMapEvent('click', onClick);

    //  ////Keep track of bounds in state to trigger renders
    const [parentBounds, setBounds] = useState(parentMap.getBounds());
    function onZoomOut(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>): void {
    }

    function onZoomIn(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>): void {
    }

    //  const [parentZoom, setZoom] = useState(parentMap.getZoom())
    const onChange = useCallback(() => {
        // update the minimap's view to match the parent map's center and zoom
        setBounds(parentMap.getBounds());

        let zoom = parentMap.getZoom() - zoomDifference;
        if (zoom < 0)
            zoom = 0;
        minimap.setView(parentMap.getCenter(), zoom);
    }, [minimap, parentMap, zoomDifference]);
    //Listen to events on the parent map
    const handlers = useMemo(() => ({ move: onChange, zoom: onChange }), [onChange]);
    //@ts-ignore
    useEventHandlers({ instance: parentMap }, handlers);

    //@ts-ignore
    return <>
        <Rectangle bounds={parentBounds} pathOptions={{ weight: 1 }} />
        <MiniMapButton onZoomOut={onZoomOut} onZoomIn={onZoomIn} ></MiniMapButton>
    </>
};

function useHook(arg0: boolean) {
    throw new Error('Function not implemented.');
}
```